# Is there a mathematical equation to compute the bitrate of a Cisco H.264 stream?

Tags: encoding, h.264, bitrate

I'm working on adaptive streaming for video. As I'm using a Cisco Open H.264 Encoder, I'm testing multiple configurations for the encoder. A configuration consists in a several of parameters (bps, fps, slice_mode, usage_type, rateconol_mode, keyframeInterval). I also have the width and height of the image to encode.

Is there a mathematical equation to get fps from the bps and vice versa in order to apply the best fps value to be adequate with the bps and the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because it's content dependent. Video with high motion contains more information than a nearly still scene does. Hence it takes more bits to encode.

Comment: I'd say that this statement is *technically* wrong, but practically accurate. There is a mathematical equation that will answer the OPs question, but it just the math at the heart of the encoder.

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with the work of Claude Shannon. But practically, there is no way to find the mathematical "best fps" without trial and error/binary search.